# BASIC SQL How To Select Greater than 100000 and less than 200000

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to write a select query  in pgSQL that shows items that are priced at more than `100,000` and less than or equal to `200,000`. I realise there is a `BETWEEN` function but that isn't exactly what I want.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT id FROM Item WHERE (Price = >100000 AND Price = <=200000);
```

Apologies for this being so basic just trying to learn `SQL` from the ground up..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a note, remember that `>=` and `<=` are going to make that 100,000 to 200,000 *inclusive* (i.e., you results will also include records with prices of 100,000 and 200,000)

Comment: What is the datatype of Price?

Comment: To learn the very fundamental basics, grab a manual or a tutorial somewhere. It's off topic here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have problems with your `<=` and `>=` conditions. the `=` is always last and only occurs once.

```
SELECT id FROM Item WHERE Price >=100000 AND Price <=200000;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices:

```
SELECT id
FROM Item
WHERE Price > 100000
AND Price <= 200000
```

Or use the inclusive BETWEEN with an adjusted lower bound:

```
SELECT id
FROM Item
WHERE Price BETWEEN 100001 AND 200000
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your exact problem it, your query looks ok BUT you have an extra equal and space between equal and greater

```
SELECT id FROM Item WHERE (Price = >100000 AND Price = <=200000);
                                  ^                  ^
```

should be

```
SELECT id FROM Item WHERE (Price >= 100000 AND Price <= 200000);
```

Also see from other answers the parens are not required in this case, but should not hurt.

Comment: I'm not sure about postgresql, but `=>` should probably be `>=`

Comment: Guess fallen out of habit @valverij since some DBMS accept. But you are right, it is safer. Edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM Item WHERE Price > 100000 AND Price < 200000
```